How can I check which demands were placed on an Azure DevOps Pipelines run?
When creating a pipeline run manually (i.e. not from a trigger) you can specify demands, which I sometimes do if I want to check the run on a specific agent within the specified pool (e.g. "Agent.Name" equals "blah"). However, after the run has been scheduled, is there any way to check which demands were configured for that run?

Just out of curiosity, what is your scenario? I.e. why do you need to check the which demands are configured for a particular run?

U are using yaml based files or the ado pipeline creator ? In yaml you can specify the demands  ```pool:
name: MyPool
demands:

myCustomCapability   # exists check for myCustomCapability
Agent.Version -equals 2.144.0 # equals check for Agent.Version 2.144.0```


@RuiJarimba When there are multiple queued builds I sometimes need to be able to figure out which builds are for which sets of demands, e.g. when discussing with the team when a particular build is likely to start

@LukeCelitan I'm using pipeline creator mostly (a couple are using YAML) but it should not matter because I'm talking about demands configured against the run not the pipeline

According to this doc Builds - Get, you can get demands using this REST API.


This looks like exactly what I need. Any hints on how to use it? When I call the given URL GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=7.0 I do get a JSON object which seems to represent a build as it has fields like id, buildNumber, requestedBy etc. However there is no demands field at all, even when I specify a build ID that I know I triggered with demands. It's not like the field is just an empty array, it's just missing altogether

Testing this API on my side, I have the same issue. There isn't demand object in the response body. I have checked the network trace and agent logs and don't find anything related to demand.  It seems to be a bug in the doc Builds - Get. If so, there isn't any way to get the demands of the build. I would suggest submitting a feature request on Developer Community. You can share the link here, so that others want the same feature can submit a vote to increase its priority.
